# Remove NSUserDefaults in App Group

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, ios-app-group

Normally to clear NSUserDefaults I would do

```
NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
```

How would I delete the NSUSerDefaults if stored in an app group?  What value do I use for appDomain?

Comment: How can I do this? Could you share with me? Thankss

Answer (score 1):

as soon as your app group and NSUserDefaults is configured correctly there is working around the same as with standardUserDefautls just with specified app group like this ->

`[[[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"__YOUR_APP_GROUP_NAME__"] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];`